# Applscript workflow not working from menu

Tags: applescript, automator

I'm new to apple scripting. I'm trying to write a couple of scripts to let you skip forward/back 5 seconds in iTunes using a global hot key. Here's the script for jumping backwards:

```
tell application "iTunes"
if player state is stopped then return

try
    set player position to (get player position) + (-5)
end try
end tell
```

It works just fine when running from within Automator and iTunes responds by rewinding 5 seconds. And I have successfully saved it as a service and it's sitting in /Library/Services.

However, when I run the script from the Services menu, nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A reboot of my computer fixed the issue.